# Array to string conversion

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, associative-array

In this code, I'm trying to display image from an array however, I'm getting array to string conversion error. From what I've googled, you'll have to use `print_r` in order to print string but I'm not exactly sure how I can do that:

```
<?php
$item_array = array(
  1 => array('product_img' => "images/013_8c9f517a.jpg",
            'product_name' => "black tshirt",
            'product_price' => "€99.00"),
  2 => array('product_img' => "images/014_28ded7a4.jpg",
            'product_name' => "white tshirt",
            'product_price' => "€99.00"));

echo "<img src=$item_array[1]['product_img']>";
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use proper string concatenation. Change this line:

```
echo "<img src=$item_array[1]['product_img']>";
```

To one of these options:

```
echo "<img src={$item_array[1]['product_img']}>";
echo "<img src=".$item_array[1]['product_img'].">";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Extracting a temporary variable could make things a whole lot easier:

```
$src = $item_array[1]['product_img'];
echo "<img src=${src}>";
```